# Convert MSSS Fixed Number to ANSI Time "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"

Tags: sql, date, time, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ansi-sql

I am trying to convert a fixed number to time without the date as `hh:mm:ss AM/PM` - so `67683000` would be `06:48:03 PM`; `22814000` = `06:20:14 AM`. I had `% 43200000` to calculate as the remainder. My MSSS SQL code (cursor) is below. In Snowflake, my code (not as a cursor) needs to be translated to ANSI but I'm getting errors and can't figure out why.

Expected results in `HH:MM:SS AM (or PM)`

---

### `MSSS - correct`

```
`CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(ms, AS_AIRED_START_TIME % 43200000, 0), 108)  
+ '' ''  
+ CASE  WHEN AS_AIRED_START_TIME % 86400000 > 43199999       
THEN ''PM''  
ELSE ''AM'' END
```

[Aired Time] `

---

### `ANSI - wrong`

```
`TO_VARCHAR(255), (DATE_PART(MILLISECOND, AS_AIRED_START_TIME % 43200000, 0), 108)  
+ ' '  
+ CASE  WHEN AS_AIRED_START_TIME % 86400000 > 43199999   
THEN 'PM'  
ELSE 'AM' END
```

as AiredTime`

---

### `ANSI - close but not exact`

```
`TO_CHAR(TRUNC(fed.AS_AIRED_START_TIME/3600),'FM9999999999900')      
|| ':'   
|| TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(fed.AS_AIRED_START_TIME,3600)/60),'FM00')    
|| ':'   
|| TO_CHAR(MOD(fed.AS_AIRED_START_TIME,60),'FM00')`
```

### `Result: 17248:36:40`

### `ANSI - wrong`

```
`TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(fed.AS_AIRED_START_TIME,0)`
```

---

### `ANSI - wrong`

```
`TO_VARCHAR(DATEADD(millisecond,500, current_timestamp),'hh:mi:ss')`
```

---

### `Excel - conversion`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LUgM.png)

so given 1800000, I would calculate as 1800000/1000/60sec/60min/24hours = 00:30:00 = 30 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with TEST_DATA
  as (
    select 67683000::integer as AS_AIRED_START_TIME -- PM
    union all
    select 24483000::integer -- AM
)
select to_char(timeadd(ms, AS_AIRED_START_TIME, to_time('00:00:00')), 'HH12:MI:SS AM')
from TEST_DATA;
```